Find a number in a list that is closest to another number
I have some sample data below and I need to find the scenario where the value is closest to but no greater than 94,000,100. The answer would be 12. How do I accomplish this in SAS? This is a piece of code within a large SAS program. Any input is greatly appreciated!


Is your data sorted by value descending?

Perhaps first filter the data to be less than or equal to the target N (here, N = 94,000,100) and then pick the maximum of those. Something like this:
select scenarios, rank, value
from proclib.datatable
where value <= &N
having value = max(value)

SAS does not require a group by for using having.

If your data is sorted descending by value, then simply read the data until you hit a value less than 94,000,100. Then save the scenario in a macro variable
data have;
input scenario rank value;
format comma20;
datalines;
189 1  100500000 
27  2  100000000 
57  3  99500000  
159 4  99000000  
103 5  98500000  
113 6  98000000  
176 7  97500000  
108 8  97000000  
184 9  96500000  
80  10 96000000  
105 11 95500000  
58  12 95000000  
12  13 94000000  
138 14 93000000  
185 15 92000000  
;

%let v = 94100000;

data _null_;
   set have;
   if value < &v. then do;
      call symputx('closest_scenario', scenario);
      stop;
   end;
run;

%put &=closest_scenario.;


Thank you for your suggestions! This is what I ended up with. The code in the parenthesis filtered the data to only include values that are no larger than the specified number &v and then take the maximum of those values. This is the record that is closest to but not greater than &v. I then use "select...into" to write the scenario number into a macro variable "scen".
select scenario
into :scen trimmed
from (select scenario, value
    from have
    where value le &v.
    having value=max(value));
%put &scen;


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

The overkill method: solving it with linear programming. Totally unnecessary but a fun exercise nonetheless. This program finds the minimum difference between the number and the max value that it cannot exceed.
proc optmodel;
    set <num> scenario;
    num value{scenario};
    num max_val = 94000100;

    read data have into scenario=[scenario] value;

    var x{scenario} binary;

    /* Only select one value */
    con select_one: sum{s in scenario} x[s] = 1;

    /* The selected value must <= the maximum value */
    con le_max {s in scenario}: x[s]*value[s] <= max_val;

    /* Minimize the difference from the max value */
    min closest = max_val - sum{s in scenario} (x[s]*value[s]);

    solve;

    print x value;
run;


